# Using ScreenSlider from developer.android.com . How to jump to specific page?

Tags: android, animation, android-fragments

I am using ScreenSlider like this http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html . It is perfectly running where I am using 5 pages . Now what I want is to directly jump from one page to another . Like e.g  user is at 2 page and on clicking a button jumps to 5 page . How could I implement this. Is there any predefined methods .Please help?

Comment: check this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setCurrentItem(int, boolean)

Comment: thanks but Please be specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use setCurrentItem [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setCurrentItem(int](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setCurrentItem%28int)

```
mViewPager.setCurrentItem(4) // For moving to 5th page
```

or

```
mViewPager.setCurrentItem(4, true) // move with with animation
```